# redirecting in react router 6 and reactjs 17

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router

I want to redirect the user after successful login to the home page, But nothing works.
This is my Login.js component
Also, I could not get parameter URL in class-based components and I was forced to use functional component and I use `let params=useParams();` to get URL parameters

```
function Login(props) {
  const sendSms = async (e=null) => {
          if (typeof(securityCode) !=='undefined' && securityCode.toString().length === 6) {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login/' ,{
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          mobile,
          securityCode
        })
      });
        const data = await response.json();
        let result=data.result;
          let message=data.message;
          if (result === 'success') {
          clearInterval(sms_interval);
           setToken(data.data);
           return navigate("/", { replace: true }); //important
            return false;
          } else {
            setAlertClass('alert-danger');
            setAlertMessage(message);
          }

        return false;
    }
         fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/send_sms/' ,{
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          mobile
        })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 
          let result=data.result;
          let message=data.message;
          if (result === 'success') {
          
            let sms_timer = 120;
            setSmsInteral(setInterval(function () {
              if (sms_timer > 0) {
            
            }, 1000)
            );
          } else {
                      }
          
        });

    return false;
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useHistory` hook is no longer present with React Router 6.

Try to use the `useNavigate` hook and convert the function to use `async / await`:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const verify = async (e = null) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login/", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          mobile,
          securityCode,
        }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      let result = data.result;
      let message = data.message;
      if (result === "success") {
        clearInterval(sms_interval);
        setToken(data.data);
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        sms_alert_element.classList.add("alert-danger");
        sms_alert_element.innerText = message;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: But after redirected my setInterval continues in Login.js

Comment: Where is `sms_interval` initialization?

Comment: at first I sent a verify code to user by sms, and immediately setInterval starts to count  down two minutes.

Comment: Ok, but where do you call `setInterval`? Can you post that code?

Comment: Eventually I use state to solve this problem . Is it correct?

Comment: const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setToken } = props
  const [alert_message, setAlertMessage] = useState(null);
  const [alert_class, setAlertClass] = useState(null);
  const [active_green_form, setActiveGreenForm] = useState(null);
  const [active_orange_form, setActiveOrangeForm] = useState('active_orange_form');
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState();
  const [securityCode, setSecurityCode] = useState(0);
  const [sms_interval,setSmsInteral]=useState(null);

const sendSms = async (e=null) => {
    if(e){
      e.preventDefault()
    }

Comment: if (typeof(securityCode) !=='undefined' && securityCode.toString().length === 6) {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login/' ,{
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          mobile,
          securityCode
        })
      });
        const data = await response.json();
        let result=data.result;
          let message=data.message;

Comment: if (result === 'success') {
          clearInterval(sms_interval);
           setToken(data.data);
           return navigate("/", { replace: true }); //important
          //  return <Navigate to={Home} replace={true} />;

            return false;
          } else {
            setAlertClass('alert-danger');
            setAlertMessage(message);
            // enableButton('send_sms_button');
          }

        return false;
    }

Comment: fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/send_sms/' ,{
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          mobile
        })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 
          let result=data.result;
          let message=data.message;
          if (result === 'success') {
            setAlertClass('alert-info'); 
            setActiveGreenForm('active_green_form');
            setActiveOrangeForm('');

Comment: disableButton('send_sms_button', '<div class="col col-3"></div> <div class="col col-auto">Try Again</div><div class="col-3" id="sms_timer">120</div>');
            let sms_timer = 120;
            setSmsInteral(setInterval(function () {
              console.log(sms_timer)

Comment: if (sms_timer > 0) {
                sms_timer--;
                disableButton('send_sms_button', '<div class="col col-3"></div> <div class="col col-auto">Try Again</div><div class="col-3" id="sms_timer">' + sms_timer + '</div>');   } else {
     clearInterval(sms_interval)
                enableButton('send_sms_button', '<div class="col col-12">Send Verify Code</div>')
              }
            }, 1000)
            );
          } else {
            setAlertClass('alert-danger');
            
            enableButton('send_sms_button');
          }
          
        });

Comment: Also please tell me how to use redirect in class based components?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code to it?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post